# How to use variable from another class for scanner input?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

The problem I have encountered is as follows:
I want to create 10 row outputs representing docking spaces for ships.

Each row contains the ship name and size, which are inputs provided by the applicaiton user. These inputs are retreived using the Scanner class, and should be stored in an array (shipName,ShipSize in each array element).

I would then like to print the rows, as seen in the printArray method below.

I have encountered issues when using the Scanner. When I print the array I get null. I'm unsure if i'm passing the variable from the ship class correctly and if it's saving in the array.
Can you help?

Here is the code:

```
 import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Choose an option: 1-3");
        System.out.println("1. Dock");
        System.out.println("2. Undock");
        System.out.println("3. Status");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int menu = scan.nextInt();

        switch (menu) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("1. Dock");

                dock();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("2. Undock");
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("3. Status");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("No such option");
                break;
        }


    }

    public static void dock(){
        String[] dock1 = new String[10];

        Ship ship = new Ship();

            System.out.println("Enter ship's name: ");
            ship.setShipName(scan.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Enter ship's size: ");
            ship.setShipSize(scan.nextLine());


            printArray(dock1);

    }

    public static void printArray(String dock1[]){


        for (int i = 0; i<dock1.length ; i++) {
            System.out.print(dock1[i] + " ");
        }
    }

}
```

Ship class

```
public class Ship {

public  String shipName;
public  String shipSize;

public String getShipName() {
    return shipName;
}

public void setShipName(String shipName) {
    this.shipName = shipName;
}

public String getShipSize() {

    return shipSize;
}

public void setShipSize(String shipSize) {
    this.shipSize = shipSize;
}

public Ship() {

}}
```

Comment: you aren't placing the Ship object into anything, let alone an array. Furthermore dock1 is a String array, you want a Ship[] dock1

Comment: you are initializing dock1 but you are not adding anything to the array. dock1.length is zero

Comment: So how do I fix this so I can add to the array?

Comment: i believe you can use `Ship[]` to store the ship objects and post that you can read the values in printArray as per your need.

Comment: So change to  Ship[] dock1 = new Ship[10]; then what would go underneath  System.out.println("Enter ship's name: ");?

Comment: i hope below answers will help you a lot ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a refactored **ship** class:

```
public class Ship {

private String shipName;
private String shipSize;

public Ship(String shipName, String shipSize) {
    this.shipName = shipName;
    this.shipSize = shipSize;
}

public String getShipName() {
    return shipName;
}

public String getShipSize() {
    return shipSize;
}

public void setShipName(String shipName) {
    this.shipName = shipName;
}

public void setShipSize(String shipSize) {
    this.shipSize = shipSize;
}
```

}

Then you can begin fixing your errors in the **Main.java**:

1. You are always creating a new array. The ships will be stored, but with the next call they all gone.
2. You use a String array. Because you are creating objects of your own class, you should store them in a array of the ship class.
3. You don't get a dock number or you are checking if there is still space in the dock.
4. You have only once the chance to do a operation once

So there is a solution:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Create a global array
    private static Ship[] dock1 = new Ship[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Repeat until the program gets closed
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Choose an option: 1-3");
            System.out.println("1. Dock");
            System.out.println("2. Undock");
            System.out.println("3. Status");
            System.out.println("4. Exit");

            int menu = scan.nextInt();

            switch (menu) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("1. Dock");
                    dock();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("2. Undock");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("3. Status");
                    printArray();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.exit(0);
                default:
                    System.out.println("No such option");
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void dock(){

        System.out.println("Enter ship's name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter ship's size: ");
        String size = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the ships dock:");

        //Check if the dock number is valid
        int i = Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());
        if (i >= 0 && i < 10 && dock1[i] == null){
            //Add ship to the dock
            dock1[i] = new Ship(name, size);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Couldn't dock");
        }

    }

    public static void printArray(){

        System.out.println("Docks:");

        for (int i = 0; i < dock1.length ; i++) {

            if (dock1[i] != null){
                System.out.println(i + ".: " + dock1[i].getShipName() + "(" + dock1[i].getShipSize() + ")");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(i + ".: Empty");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to assign the array a value thats why its null.

```
public static void dock(){
    int count = 10;
    Ship[] dock1 = new Ship[count];

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
         Ship ship = new Ship();

         System.out.println("Enter ship's name: ");
         ship.setShipName(scan.nextLine());

         System.out.println("Enter ship's size: ");
         ship.setShipSize(scan.nextLine());

         dock1[i] = ship;
    }

    printArray(dock1);
}

public static void printArray(String dock1[]){
    for (int i = 0; i<dock1.length ; i++) {
        System.out.print(dock1[i].getShipName() + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but is there another way without using an arrayList? I just want to use an array.

Comment: i beleive the OP is using an array because it mirrors the actual behavior of a dock in real life

Comment: Yes! Exactly. The dock size cannot change

Comment: @Luke101 @S.smith94  how this would work  `dock1[i] = ship;` ?

Comment: Edited, had a slight bug

Answer (score 0):

I would just change the dock Method.  If you are looking to print a bunch of ships in this manner then using a List or ArrayList would work as you can add or remove elements at your will with little cost to performance.

```
public static void dock(){
    Ship ship = new Ship();

    System.out.println("Enter ship's name: ");
    ship.setShipName(scan.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Enter ship's size: ");
    ship.setShipSize(scan.nextLine());

    System.out.println(ship.getShipName() + " size: " + ship.getShipSize());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to initialize an array that contains ships and a capactiy to keep track of the number of ships in your dock right after your scanner object.

```
Ship[] dock1 = new Ship[10];
int dockCapactiy = 0;
```

Then inside the dock method do the following after creating the ship

```
//check the capacity
if(dockCapactiy >= 10)
{
    System.out.println("Dock Full");
    return;
}
else
{
    dock1[dockCapacity] = ship;
    dockCapacity++;
}
```

Finally when you want to print the dock you check if the ship exists at an index and if it does, you print the contents

```
for(int i = 0; i < dock1.length; i++)
{
   if(dock1[i] == null)
   {
       System.out.println("Dock " + i + " is empty");
   }
   else
   {
       System.out.println("Dock " + i + ": " + dock1[i].getShipName() + ", Size: " + dock1[i].getShipSize());
   }
}
```

Comment: if it was able to fix your problem, please mark as answer to close the question. if it did not, let me know and I can help make anything in my answer more clear @S.smith94

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to keep your code and add what's needed for it to work:

```
public static void dock(){

Ship[] dock1 = new Ship[10];

for(int i=0; i<10;i++){

    Ship ship = new Ship();

    System.out.println("Enter ship's name: ");
    ship.setShipName(scan.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Enter ship's size: ");
    ship.setShipSize(scan.nextLine());

    dock1[i] = ship;
}

    printArray(dock1);

}

public static void printArray(Ship dock1[]){

for (int i = 0; i<dock1.length ; i++) {
    System.out.println(dock1[i].getShipName() + " " + dock1[i].getShipSize());

   }
}
```